# Looking for a Statistical Modelling Technique for a Credibility Scoring Model

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I’m in the process of developing a model that assigns a credibility score to fatigue reports within an organization. Employees can report feeling “tired” an unlimited number of times throughout the year, and the goal of my model is to assess the credibility of these reports.

The model should consider several factors, including:

- The historical pattern of reporting (e.g., if an employee consistently reports fatigue on specific days like Fridays or Mondays).
- The frequency of fatigue reports within a specified timeframe (e.g., the past month).
- The nature of the employee’s duties immediately before and after each fatigue report.

I’m currently contemplating which statistical modelling techniques would be most suitable for this task. Two approaches that I’m considering are:

1. Conducting a descriptive analysis, assigning weights to past behaviors, and computing a score based on these weights.
2. Developing a Bayesian model to calculate the probability of a fatigue report being genuine, given that it has been reported by a particular employee.

I’m interested in hearing suggestions for state-of-the-art algorithms or techniques that could be applied to this problem.

Comment: I think you should define "credibility" in objective terms, e.g. when a user leaves the organization or takes a long medical leave, their fatigue reports are deemed credible. Once you have identified the "real" objective (i.e. predicting employees that will be quitting), you can then proceed with a machine learning model that predict that target variable.

Comment: Thanks @noe, it makes sense but there is a slight problem. Like 99% of the employees won't leave but they will keep on marking "Fatigue" or "Tired" to take advantage of the loophole. My objective is to find out if the reporting is genuine. Or at least build a credibility score around that.

Comment: What does it mean for a report to be "genuine?" If you are able to describe what is and isn't genuine, then this problem becomes much simpler. IMO, it would be wiser to spend more time on defining explicitly what it means for a report to be "genuine" or not, and through this business logic assign a label. Alternatively, I think this could be phrased as an outlier detection problem if you define a genuine report as someone who reports above average, given their job/time/tenure etc.